# Geometric significace of oblique parabola parameters

Tags: analytic-geometry

What is the geometric significance of constants $ (h,k,m) $ in this oblique parabola equation?

$$ y=  m x \pm \sqrt{m x h + k^2}$$

[image]

Graph made with $ (h,k,m)=( 2,-1,0.5)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You  can start from the general equation of a parabola:
$$
Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0
$$
 with $B^2-4AC=0$, where the coefficients are linked to the properties of the parabola from classical results ( that you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#General_Cartesian_form)).

Than solve the equation for $y$ and   compare the result with your formula.

Comment: I am asking for geometric interpretation of linear parameters $(h,k)$ and the dimensionless parameter $m$  but not  how to derive it.

Comment: Since $A,B,C,D,E,F$ have a geometric meaning ( as you can see in the linked page), if you know how $h,k,m$ are derived you can find also their geometric interpretation.